# Accessing named parameter in custom route from within a controller

Tags: plugin-development, routes, modules

I have a custom module in which I am setting a front end route that routes through to a controller. Like so:

```
 Event::on(
    UrlManager::class,
    UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
    function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
        $event->rules['my-account/orders/<order>/pause'] = 'custom-module-name/order/pause-order';
    }
);
```

This works fine but how can I access that `<order>` named parameter within my controller? Is the only way to use `craft::$app->request->getSegment(3);`?

Comment: If this is possible to you, you could instead use an endpoint like `my-account/orders/<order>?action=pause` and access the `pause` via `$param = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getParam('action');` Might be an easier solution.

Comment: I could do that, yes. Was more curious as to if it were possible. I would prefer to keep the "nice" url without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Hat tip to Andrew Welch for the answer.

With the route `my-account/orders/<order>/pause` it's possible to simply add the parameter to my controller method definition and it gets populated from the named parameter in the route.

```
  public function actionPauseOrder($order = null)
    {

       // do stuff
    }
```

The value of the named parameter `order` can then be accessed in the function as one would expect.

Super simple!